# INSERT IN FOXPRO

Tags: visual-foxpro

I HAVE iNSERT TO TABLE AG_MAS IN fOXPRO FOLLOW:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=pl_prov.dbf");
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            string strSQL = "insert into ag_mas";
            strSQL += "(ag_code,ag_level,ag_group,ag_rcode,ag_status,";
            strSQL += "ag_type,ag_gender,ag_lname,ag_fname,ag_add1,";
            strSQL += "ag_add2,ag_add3,ag_add4,ag_class,ag_vouch,";
            strSQL += "pl_prov,pl_zone,ag_jdate,ag_ddate,ag_dbrith,ag_bank  ,";
            strSQL += "ag_bankno,ag_telno,ag_faxno,ag_email,ag_ppay,";
            strSQL += "ag_contno,ag_dcont,ag_ladate,ag_lpolno,ag_lendno,";
            strSQL += "ag_comm,ag_maxcom,ag_orcomm,ag_om1com,ag_om2com,";
            strSQL += "ag_om3com,ag_oy1com, ag_oy2com,ag_oy3com,ag_network)";
            strSQL += "values (";
            strSQL += "'" + textBox1.Text + "',";//ag_code
            strSQL += "'" + textBox2.Text + "',";//ag_level
            strSQL += "'" + textBox3.Text + "',";//ag_group
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                //ag_rcode
            strSQL += "'" + textBox4.Text + "',";//ag_status
            strSQL += "'" + textBox22.Text + "',";//ag_type
            strSQL += "'" + textBox5.Text + "',";//ag_gender
            strSQL += "'" + textBox6.Text + "',";//ag_lname
            strSQL += "'" + textBox7.Text + "',";//ag_fname
            strSQL += "'" + textBox8.Text + "',";//ag_add1
            strSQL += "'" + textBox9.Text + "',";//ag_add2
            strSQL += "'" + comboBox1.Text + "',";//ag_add3
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                   //ag_add4
            strSQL += "'" + textBox10.Text + "',";//ag_class
            strSQL += "'" + textBox11.Text + "',";//ag_vouch
            strSQL += "'" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "',";//pl_prov
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                   //pl_zone
            strSQL += "'" + textBox12.Text + "',";  //ag_jdate
            strSQL += "'1987/10/10',";                             //ag_ddate
            strSQL += "'1987/10/10',";                             //ag_dbirth
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                   //ag_bank
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                   //ag_bankno
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                   //ag_telno
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                   //ag_faxno
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                   //ag_email
            strSQL += "'" + textBox13.Text + "',"; //ag_ppay
            strSQL += "'" + textBox15.Text + "',";//ag_contno
            strSQL += "'" + textBox14.Text + "',";//ag_dcont
            strSQL += "'1987/10/10', ";               //ag_ladate
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                  //ag_lpopno
            strSQL += "' ' ,";                                  //ag_lendno
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_comm
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_maxcom
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_orcomm
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_om1com
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_om2com
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_om3comm
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_oy1com
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_oy2Xcom
            strSQL += "0,";                                  //ag_oy3com
            strSQL += "' ')";                                  //ag_network
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connect);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

BUT I CAN'T INSERT. BECAUSE ERROR "DATA MISS MATCH" PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Frank on the issue with dates... It could also be trying to do a text into a numeric field (or any other such swapping).

However, a bigger issue might be if/when you get into using a true SQL database such as Oracle, SQL-Server, MySQL, etc... (not that I have anything against VFP and have been programming with Foxpro since '85)  But doing SQL statements like you have, especially in any web-based system would leave you wide-open to SQL-injection attacks.

Its better to use parameterized query/insert/update/deletes.

Answer (score 0):

A Data Type Mismatch error occurs when you try to insert an inappropriate data type into a field.  For example, if you try to store a string into an integer field.

At first glance I think the format of your dates is the problem.  Change "'1987/10/10'," to "{^1987-10-10},".

If changing the dates does not correct the problem, it would be helpful if you could show me the result of the strSQL variable and structure of the ag_mas table.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Frank in regards to a solution and I believe that DRapp has a valid point about how you are going about your insert statement.  To add to DRapp’s suggestion, I’d like to point out that you could use [LINQ to VFP](http://linqtovfp.codeplex.com/) to handle writing all your sql commands.